# SQL Server Performance: derived table vs. common table expression (CTE)

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, common-table-expression, derived-table

Is there any performance gain using a CTE over a derived table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used CTEs a lot and it does actually appear to run faster in some scenarios.  The server was fairly well loaded, the variation in times on runs was pretty significant, and I can't believe the execution plan was that different, but it still seemed like the ones with the CTE performed better.

Answer (score 3):

From what I have read and my limited use of them, no, they are just easier to read and can reference themselves.